# How to sort items in Ext.grid.NumberColumn by values?

Tags: sorting, extjs

Could you please show me the way to sort all items in Ext.grid.NumberColumn (contained in a grid) by their values? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

sorting is done in store of grid:

```
......
store:  new Ext.data.Store ( {
  .....
  sortInfo: {
    field:      'your_int_column',
    direction:  'ASC'
  },       
  reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader ( { },
    [   
       'FirstName',
       'LastName',
      { name: 'your_int_column', type: 'int' }
    ]    
  ),
  .....
} ),
....
```